# glitch free state machine outputs

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog, state-machine

in the paper 
*Coding And Scripting Techniques For FSM Designs With Synthesis-Optimized, Glitch-Free Outputs*  by Clifford E. Cummings

for a glitch free statemachine, it refers to separating state register ( i.e. reset block) from the state transition block:

[image]
[image]

my question is, in terms of real-life behavior ( not simulation, as simulations don't portray glitches) is it equivalent to the following:

```
always@(posedge clk or negedge rst_n or ws or go)

 if( !rst_n) 
   state<= IDLE; // initializing the state  

 else begin 

  case(state) 
      IDLE: begin

        if(go) state<= read;
         else state<= idle;

       end

       // rest of state transition code
  endcase

 end

// the *registered outputs sequential always block* goes here
```

Comment: why the down vote? it is legitimate question, and i'm trying to learn..

Answer (score 1):

it is different. At least for one thing. In your example

```
if( !rst_n) 
  state<= IDLE; // initializing the state  
else begin 
 case(state)
```

when `state` is reset to IDLE, the `else` part will not execute and the `case` statement will not be executed  while rst_n is low (and not at the same clock pulse).

In the Cummings' example, `state` will be evaluated at the same clock edge despite the value of reset by the 
`always @(state, ...)`
block